# Cache bypassing for XMLHttpRequests

Tags: javascript, caching, xmlhttprequest

I would like to bypass the cache when making XMLHttpRequest. I have found a solution thanks to :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#bypassing_the_cache

But I don't understand completely the solution...

replacing :
`request.open('GET', url);`

by :
`request.open('GET', url + ((/\?/).test(url) ? "&" : "?") + (new Date()).getTime());`

Works nicely, but I don't understand :

- What is the object `(/\?/)` from which we call the method "test(url)"?
- In which case do I have to put "?" and in which case do I have to put "&" at
  end of urls, before appending `Date().getTime()`?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is the object (/\?/) from which we call the method "test(url)"?**

It is a regular expression literal, and [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is a method of the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instance that is created from that literal. It is checking if the `url` already has a param list by checking if `url` already has the param list delimiter `?`

**In which case do I have to put "?" and in which case do I have to put "&" at end of urls, before appending Date().getTime()?**

It depends if the url has a param list yet or not. So if your `url` was :

```
http://example.com/somepage.php
```

There is no param list and you would need to add the `?` to denote the start of the url param list

```
http://example.com/somepage.php?1234567
```

If your `url` already has a `?` like the above you would need to add the `&` to denote a different param in the list so that you do not change the value of a previously existing param

```
http://example.com/somepage.php?someparam=somevalue&12345678
```